# Do not allow Site Owners to open "Manage site features" in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a requirement where associated sharepoint owners group should not have access to enable/disable site features.

When I tried to uncheck "Manage Web Site" checkbox from permission level, it will remove other options like Delete this site under site actions.

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Manage your SharePoint team site settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-your-SharePoint-team-site-settings-8376034d-d0c7-446e-9178-6ab51c58df42)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/82379)